# Can you instantiate a class in another project?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I wonder if it is possible to make the call of a function that is in a class of another project.
This is the structure of both projects:

[image]

Comment: If you include the correct file(s), why couldn't you?

Comment: Yes , You can but load the laravel autoload classess.

Comment: You can do so as long as you load the class, but it would be better if you set your other project in a repository and then add it as a dependency of the laravel project on composer.

Comment: Can you give me an idea on how to do dependency?

Comment: It's a personal link, yes..but it does show how you can create a library for use in Laravel, making use of both service providers and facades for easy loading into Laravel: https://github.com/pazuzu156/KParser

Answer (score 0):

This would be an **anti-pattern** use.  you want all classes available, by autoloading them.  If you need that class, you would want to find a way to implement it into your existing bundle, or add a new bundle containing this helper functionality embedded within so that its loaded in, then use it that way. Otherwise there is no system for this, since it is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a repository on GitHub or Bitbucket and add your *Project 1* to that repository. This implies:

1. Creating a Git repository
2. "Transforming" that local project onto a package using [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/) ([see this](http://blog.jgrossi.com/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/) for more info)

Having this, you'll simply need to edit the `composer.json` file on the Laravel project and add your package as a dependency. Once you execute `composer update`, the *Project 1* will be available on the vendor directory and you can instanciate the class by its namespace.